# Como setar um checkbox como checado?

Tags: java, android

Bom dia, tenho um layout com alguns checkbox, esses estão desativados para que o usuário não consiga marcar os mesmos pois por questões de segurança essa checagem deve ocorrer via código, tenho o seguinte código: 
Preciso setar o checkbox como checado via código java e não via XML, pois irei montar uma lógica com essas informações.

```
public class ZXingJarDemoActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String editText1 = null;
    protected static final TextView Dispositivo = null;
    private static final EditText bscdispo = null;
    private CheckBox d2201;

    private Handler  handler = new Handler();
    private TextView txtScanResult;
    private TextView textbox1;
    private View validado;
    private TextView output;
    private EditText bscdispo1;
    private String buscar;






    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        d2201=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.d2201);
        bscdispo1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bscdispo1); 
        txtScanResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scan_result);
        textbox1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scan_result2);

        d2201.setChecked(true);
```

quando executo a aplicação ela abre e fecha dando crash, se eu remover o código "d2201.setChecked(true); ele funciona normalmente.

**LogCat - Atualizado**

http://freetexthost.com/if0ulvi6sr

**Activy completa**

```
package msinfomg.leitorcodigobarras;

import msinfomg.codebar.leitor.R;


public class ZXingJarDemoActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String editText1 = null;
    protected static final TextView Dispositivo = null;
    private static final EditText bscdispo = null;
    private CheckBox d2201;

    private Handler  handler = new Handler();
    private TextView txtScanResult;
    private TextView textbox1;
    private View validado;
    private TextView output;
    private EditText bscdispo1;
    private String buscar;






    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        d2201=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.d2201);
        bscdispo1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bscdispo1); 
        txtScanResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scan_result);
        textbox1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scan_result2);

        d2201.setChecked(true);             


        View botao = findViewById(R.id.Botao);

        botao.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(ZXingJarDemoActivity.this, R.layout.capture,
                        R.id.viewfinder_view, R.id.preview_view, true);
            }         


        });

 }

  //  BOTÃO BUSCAR - BUSCA O DISPOSITIVO QUE ESTA DIGITADO NO CAMPO DE BUSCA
    public void scan_dispositivo(View v) {

        buscar = bscdispo1.getText().toString();

        if ( buscar.contentEquals("7119")) {
            setContentView(R.layout.d7119);
         }
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:
                IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,
                        resultCode, data);
                if (scanResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                final String result = scanResult.getContents();
                if (result != null) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if ( ((String) txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("") ){
                           txtScanResult.setText(result);
                        } else {
                            textbox1.setText(result);
                        }
                           if ( !((String) txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("") && ((String) textbox1.getText()).trim().equals("") ){
                                 IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(ZXingJarDemoActivity.this, R.layout.capture2,
                                         R.id.viewfinder_view, R.id.preview_view, true);
                              } 
                           if ( !((String) txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("") && !((String) textbox1.getText()).trim().equals("") ){
                               if ( (txtScanResult.getText().toString().trim()+"A").equals(textbox1.getText().toString()) ){
                                        setContentView(R.layout.verdade);
                                     //   String lstrNomeArq;
                                        byte[] dados;


                                     //   lstrNomeArq = (txtScanResult.getText()  + ".txt");
                                        File arquivo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Banco_consig");


                                        dados = txtScanResult.getText().toString().getBytes();
                                        try {

                                        if (!arquivo.exists()) {
                                        //cria um arquivo (vazio)
                                        arquivo.createNewFile();
                                        }

                                        //caso seja um diretório, é possível listar seus arquivos e diretórios
                                        File[] arquivos = arquivo.listFiles();

                                        //escreve no arquivo
                                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arquivo, true);

                                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);


                                        bw.write((String) txtScanResult.getText());

                                        bw.newLine();

                                        bw.close();
                                        fw.close();

                                        //faz a leitura do arquivo
                                        FileReader fr = new FileReader(arquivo);

                                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                                        //equanto houver mais linhas
                                        while (br.ready()) {
                                        //lê a proxima linha
                                        String linha = br.readLine();

                                        //faz algo com a linha
                                        System.out.println(linha);
                                        }

                                        br.close();
                                        fr.close();

                                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                        }



if ( ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("2234") || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("2235") 
        || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("22401") || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("22402")
        || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("22403") || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("22404")
        || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("2464") || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("2497")
        || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("2201") || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("2202")
        || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("2203") || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("2423")
        || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("24451") || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("2207")
        || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("2212") || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("2216")
        || ((String)txtScanResult.getText()).trim().equals("1299"))  {


                                          String dispo7119 = "7119";
                                          EditText Dispositivo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dispositivo);
                                          Dispositivo.setText(dispo7119);
                                        } else {
                                          String desc = "NULL";
                                          EditText Dispositivo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dispositivo);
                                             Dispositivo.setText(desc);
                                        }


                                                   new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
                                                new java.util.TimerTask() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void run() {
                                                         txtScanResult.setText(null); 
                                                            textbox1.setText(null); 
                                                           Intent intent = getIntent();
                                                           finish();
                                                           startActivity(intent);
                                                    }
                                                }, 
                                                1900 
                                        );
                                   } 
                                   else {
                                        setContentView(R.layout.falso);
                                       ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100);
                                       toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 3545000); 
                                    }
                            } 

                        }

                        private Object trim() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return null;
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
    public void voltar(View v) {
        txtScanResult.setText(null); 
        textbox1.setText(null); 
       Intent intent = getIntent();
       finish();
       startActivity(intent);
   }
    public void sobre(View v) {
         setContentView(R.layout.sobre);
    }

}
```

**Arquivo main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fundo_main"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/topo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Botao"
        android:layout_width="539dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/scan" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scan_result2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scan_result"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bscdispo1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scandispo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:onClick="scan_dispositivo"
        android:text="Acessar Dispositivo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sobre"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sobre"
        android:text="Sobre" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Arquivo d7119**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:background="#789854"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="                         DISPOSITIVO 7119"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="#789854"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="CHAVES:"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="19dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d2201"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="2201" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d2202"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="2202" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d2203"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="2203" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d2207"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="2207" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d2212"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="2212" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d2216"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="2216" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d2234"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="2234" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d2235"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="2235" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d2445"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="2445" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d2423"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="2423" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d2464"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="2464" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d2497"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="2497" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d22401"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="22401" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d22402"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="22402" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d22403"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="22403" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d22404"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="22404" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d24451"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="24451" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/d1299"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="1299" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/footertext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:contentDescription="31 8948-9095 Matheus Arruda | Todos os direitos reservados."
                android:ems="10"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="MS INFO-DEV 2015"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/voltar_index"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:onClick="voltar"
                android:text="Voltar" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `setContentView()` só deve ser utilizado uma vez em cada *Activity*. Use *Fragments* ou outra *Activity* se quiser apresentar outros Layouts/telas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que no seu **main.xml** não há nenhum elemento de **CheckBox**, portanto, ao tentar setar **d2201** como checado, ocorre erro.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main); // Atribui main.xml como layout da Activity

    // Cria um elemento que não existe em main.xml
    d2201=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.d2201);

    /* ... */

    // ERRO! Tenta marcar como "checked" um elemento que não existe em main.xml
    d2201.setChecked(true); 

   /* ... */
```

Portanto, você tem duas alternativas:

1. Declarar os checkboxes em **main.xml**
2. Marcar o checkbox como *checked* somente quando estiver usando **d7119.xml**